# How to encrypt big size file in python script

Tags: python, encryption

i am trying to encrypt files using python script. Below the script is successfully accomplishing the task when target files are in small sizes & quantity.

```
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

your_files = []

# os.walk gives us a 3-tuple 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("E:/test4"):
    # go through all the files we found
    for file in files:
        print(f"Simple filename: {file}")
        # the if the file is called "log" or has a ".py" in it skip it
        if file == "log" or ".py" in file:
            continue
        # if not we can add it to our list
        # your_files.append(file)

        # if you need the full path of the file you can do this
        full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        your_files.append(full_file_path)
        print(f"Full path: {file}")

print(f"Your files in a list{your_files}")
# have a look at the files list too, os.walk() creates it for you
print(your_files)
# or if you only need the dirs
#print(dirs)


key = Fernet.generate_key()

with open("thekey.key", "wb") as thekey:
    thekey.write(key)

file_exts = [".log",".chm"]
for file in your_files:
       for ext in file_exts:
            if file.endswith(ext):
                  with open(file, "rb") as thefile:
                           contents = thefile.read()
                           contents_encrypted = Fernet(key).encrypt(contents)
                  with open(file, "wb") as thefile:
                          thefile.write(contents_encrypted)
   
print("Congratulation all files are clean successfully")
```

**But when the target files are big in size & quantity, it gives error like below. Advices from experts are highly appreciated.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "E:\clear.py", line 39, in <module>     
contents = thefile.read() MemoryError
```

Comment: Did you create a new account..? This code is quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73933751/python-file-encryption-from-list from another user.

Comment: Yes sir, thats me, because dont know why this site isnt allowing me to post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the site will give you a message telling you why you can't post on that account.

Comment: as i am new here dont understand all the rules yet. thats why may be some mistakes happen while i was posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're `.read()`ing the entire file into memory.

The [Fernet implementation in `pyca/cryptography`](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/01687d63a5cb4475d84feae959bec6dea5fce3f1/src/cryptography/fernet.py#L50-L60) does not have an implementation that would support streaming (where you could feed the cipher data in chunks instead of everything at once), so you'd need to either

- implement that for Fernet, or
- switch to another cipher that supports streaming.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248615/discussion-on-answer-by-akx-how-to-encrypt-big-size-file-in-python-script).